# Why does the ovum prefers to be arrested at metaphase 2 of meosis before fertilization? What is the possible advantage of this process?

Tags: human-biology, biochemistry, reproduction

Why does the human  ovum prefers to be arrested at metaphase 2 of meosis before fertilization? What is the possible advantage of this process??Please help me with it.

Comment: In different animals meiosis is arrested at different points: it's not always metaphase 2.